# The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, app-config, .net-4.5

I have a peculiar problem.

I make a HttpWebRequest against a Url and my tests from my test library works as they should.

Then I head over to my mvc4 web application and try to call the same piece of code that I call from my test. And it fails.

Now, I know there is are some things that can go wrong here. But really, not that many things should. I know for a fact it has something to do with the web.config because whenever I change the web.config in my mvc4 application to app.config, with the **exact** same values, it works.

The target framework is .NET 4.5.

Here is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <system.net>
        <settings>
            <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>
        </settings>
    </system.net>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    </system.web>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
            <file value="..\..\logs\" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="false" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it had nothing to do with my config...DoH!

It has everything to do with the way I call the piece of code I knew was working. Since it's an async method I am calling, I need to call it from an async method, so the thread is not hanging somewhere else. Task.Run(()=> MyMethod()) did the trick.